# Compare a single-column row-set with another single-column row set in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Is there any Oracle SQL operator or function, which compares 2 result sets whether they are the exact same or not. Currently my idea is to use MINUS operator in both directions, but I am looking for a better and performanter solution to achieve. The one result set is fixed (see below), the other depends on the records.

**Very important: I am not allowed to change the schema and structure. So** `CREATE TABLE` **and** `CREATE TYPE` **etc. are not allowed here for me. Also important that oracle11g version is used where the solution must be found.**

The shema for SQL Fiddle is:

```
CREATE TABLE DETAILS (ID INT, MAIN_ID INT, VALUE INT);

INSERT INTO DETAILS VALUES (1,1,1);
INSERT INTO DETAILS VALUES (2,1,2);
INSERT INTO DETAILS VALUES (3,1,3);
INSERT INTO DETAILS VALUES (4,1,4);
INSERT INTO DETAILS VALUES (5,2,1);
INSERT INTO DETAILS VALUES (6,2,2);
INSERT INTO DETAILS VALUES (7,3,1);
INSERT INTO DETAILS VALUES (7,3,2);
```

Now this is my SQL query for doing the job well (selects MAIN_IDs of those, whose 'VALUE's are exactly the same as the given lists'):

```
SELECT DISTINCT D.MAIN_ID FROM DETAILS D WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT VALUE FROM DETAILS WHERE MAIN_ID=D.MAIN_ID
  MINUS
  SELECT * FROM TABLE(SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST(1, 2)))
AND NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT * FROM TABLE(SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST(1, 2))
  MINUS
  SELECT VALUE FROM DETAILS WHERE MAIN_ID=D.MAIN_ID)
```

The SQL Fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/25dde/7/0

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's _set quantifier_. `SELECT DISTINCT` applies to the whole selected rows. Skip those extra parentheses and simply write `SELECT DISTINCT D.MAIN_ID FROM ...`, to make code clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a collection (rather than a `VARRAY`) then you can aggregate the values into a collection and directly compare two collections:

```sql
CREATE TYPE int_list AS TABLE OF INT;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT main_id
FROM   details
GROUP BY main_id
HAVING CAST( COLLECT( value ) AS int_list ) = int_list( 1, 2 );
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | MAIN_ID |
> | ------: |
> |       2 |
> |       3 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7e15823e81d6b751b8e5056b2b7355a2)*

## Update

Based on your expanded fiddle in comments, you can use:

```sql
SELECT B.ID
FROM  BUSINESS_DATA B
      INNER JOIN BUSINESS_NAME N
      ON ( B.NAME_ID=N.ID )
WHERE N.NAME='B1'
AND   EXISTS (
        SELECT business_id
        FROM   ORDERS O
               LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE(
                 SYS.ODCIDATELIST( DATE '2021-01-03', DATE '2020-04-07', DATE '2020-05-07' )
               ) d
               ON ( o.orderdate = d.COLUMN_VALUE )
        WHERE  O.BUSINESS_ID=B.ID
        GROUP BY business_id
        HAVING COUNT( CASE WHEN d.COLUMN_VALUE IS NULL THEN 1 END ) = 0
        AND    COUNT( DISTINCT o.orderdate )
               = ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT COLUMN_VALUE) FROM TABLE( SYS.ODCIDATELIST( DATE '2021-01-03', DATE '2020-04-07', DATE '2020-05-07' ) ) )
      )
```

*(Note: Do not implicitly create dates from strings; it will cause the query to fail, without there being any changes to the query text, if a user changes their `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter. Instead use `TO_DATE` with an appropriate format model or a `DATE` literal.)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cf5310a51146de4381d64bb919467fec)*

Comment: As I try to adopt this solution, I get an ORA-00907 error here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cde975/30 
What have I done badly? What is wrong with that SQL? Very important: where I need it, I can't change the shema, so I am not eligible to define own TYPE. This SQL should return the B.ID 1 only, since only this record contains exactly the same date row set as given. According to only SQL beatifyer is the syntax correct and no parenthesis is missing... I am confused now.

Comment: @A.V. You did not say in your question that you cannot create tables/types. This solution will not work for you unless you can create the type or find a built-in type that is a collection and not a `VARRAY` (the `SYS.ODCI*LIST` types are all `VARRAY`s). As for your query, SQL beatifyer is lying to you as it is not valid Oracle syntax and you cannot use `CAST(COLLECT(ORDERDATE) AS TABLE OF DATE)` since `TABLE OF DATE` is not a defined type and, even if you could, you cannot then compare it to a `SELECT` query, you would need to compare it to an identical data type.

Comment: Yes, thats true. Sorry for it. Well, what should be the right built-in type? The type-definition is not possible.

Comment: @A.V. I do not know of one; you will have to research it or find another solution.

Comment: @A.V. Updated. However, the new query may not work if you want to match two orders on the same day in the `SYS.ODCIDATELIST`. If you always have distinct values in the `SYS.ODCIDATELIST` then it should work.

Comment: Just a last question: is it possible to avoid the double invokation of `SYS.ODCIDATELIST` and so the double construction of the temporary table from the list?

Comment: @A.V. You don't need to use any collections; you can use a sub-query factoring clause instead [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=af34d6e590a0f854a50917b01d055942).

Comment: Sorry MT0, I can only upvote You once. But Your tips, I got, worth millions of upvotes! Thanks for them. :)